# How to invoke a .Net method with unsigned integer argument from IronPython

Tags: c#, .net, clr, ironpython

The method in CSharp have two variants

```
    public class MmsValue
    {
        public MmsValue (int value)
        {
            valueReference = MmsValue_newIntegerFromInt32 (value);
        }

        public MmsValue (UInt32 value)
        {
            valueReference = MmsValue_newUnsignedFromUint32(value);
        }
```

When I call it from IronPython, it always invokes `MmsValue(int value)`. Is there a way to call `MmsValue(UInt32 value)`?

Comment: Somewhat relevant: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.clscompliantattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from the IronPython documentation: http://ironpython.net/documentation/dotnet/

If you want to control the exact overload that gets called, you can use the **Overloads** method on method objects:

```
import clr
clr.AddReference('ClassLibrary1')
from ClassLibrary1 import MmsValue
from System import UInt32    

uint32_mmsValue = MmsValue.__new__.Overloads[UInt32](MmsValue, 1)
```

This will create a instance of MmsValue using the UInt32 constructor.